# Is it possible to suspend a programs graphical processing while minimized?

Tags: c++, load, windows-8.1, cpu

I am writing this again with a little more detail because of Eric's suggestion. I have a game client, FlyFF, that is written in C++. It pays to multi-box, so I normally have 9 clients loaded at one time. It takes quite a toll on my CPU (100%) and lags each client pretty badly when I get to 5+ clients. My questions is if it is possible to completely suspend the graphical component on this game (make the screen turn black/stop processing) when minimized...but allow the game to continue it's mechanics. I remember botting a game a long time ago wherein the bot would do this automaitcally.

Comment: You should add more context and details to your question; also, add tags with your platform and language.

Comment: You can hook the paint/draw directx method (i dont know its exact name atm) like fraps does, but differently than fraps does, do not call the original function.

Comment: The game client that is written in C++ - do you have the source code, or just know that's what it was written in?

Comment: @Steve - I do have the source code, it's a publicly available code that was leaked.

Comment: @DakotaSchuch Fishy. Anyway, normally the rendering stuff is seperate from the underlying model that represents the state of the game. You'll need to find the call into the rendering engine, and simply not call it when it's time to render. This assumes that any side effects of performing the rendering don't have any effect on anything else.